# Getting the cover image of song from local media

Tags: java, android, cursor, media

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri,null,null,null,null);

   if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int imageColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);

        //Add songs to the array list
        do{
            String theArt = musicCursor.getString(imageColumn);
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(theArt);
            long songId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String songTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String songArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);

            songsArrayList.add(new Songs(songId,songTitle,songArtist,image));

        }while (musicCursor.moveToNext())
```

I want to get the cover image of the song which i am getting from the local storage,  I have no idea how to do it so i get

> int imageColumn =
>   musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);

this code on internet to get album art this is showing error when i get string from it . That accessing column  -1 , I think its not getting the right column to get the image , please let me know how to get the image from  media in the way of above code

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.downloadbro.mumusic, PID: 10877
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.downloadbro.mumusic/com.downloadbro.mumusic.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2755)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2816)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1555)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6383)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
    at com.downloadbro.mumusic.MainActivity.getSongList(MainActivity.java:80)
    at com.downloadbro.mumusic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6861)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
```

And this may give me album art but i want media art no function as such showing to me

Comment: `Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.`

Comment: what - I can actually see that but how do i fix this.

Comment: After query for media, you have to execute another query for the Albums, using the artistId, and match songs with album. there is two different colomns, see AlbumColumns, and AudioColumns.

Comment: How I am going to relate the albums with artistId please explain